# How to run specified testng.xml file in maven out of a set?

Tags: batch-file, testng, testng.xml

I am creating a batch multiple test suites for  a project. I have a regression test and a smoke test. I need to call it from the batch file, so regression I need to run after a release but smoke every day. However when I run

```
cd %projectLocation%
call mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=smokeTestRunner.xml
```

in a file it still jumps to the regression test first. Here is my surefire plugin config:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>regressionTestRunner.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        <suiteXmlFile>smokeTestRunner.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

How do I make it run only smoke test or regression test separately? Both runner.xml files and pom.xml are in the same directory

Comment: *N. B.:* `cd %projectLocation%` should read `cd /D "%projectLocation%"`…

Answer (score 0):

Try this in pom:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>{suite}.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And then run in terminal:

```
mvn clean test -Dsuite=smokeTestRunner
```

or

```
mvn clean test -Dsuite=regressionTestRunner
```